# Magento 1.9 : I am unable to generate session using soap api v2

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

Can anyone help me, regarding soap api v2 , I am unable to generate session using v2 version, is there any changes to change?

I am getting below error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error
>   cannot find parameter in

code below:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Connection API v2 + WSI-Compliance
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

//for indicom
$proxy = new SoapClient('https://magento.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test','test@123');
echo $sessionId;
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Hi @SohelRana please find the updated question

Comment: is there any possiblity to include send email after shipment creation by using below api v2

Comment: $result = $client->salesOrderShipmentCreate($session, $orderId ,$itemsQty, null,true,false));